# Using an associated many to many association in Ransack search form in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

In my spree application i have a ransack based search form for users which is as follows

```
<%= search_form_for [:admin, @search], url: admin_users_url do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email_cont, Spree.t(:email) %> <br>
        <%= f.text_field :email_cont, :class => 'fullwidth' %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :first_name_cont, Spree.t(:first_name) %> <br>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name_cont, :class => 'fullwidth' %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :last_name_cont, Spree.t(:last_name) %> <br>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name_cont, :class => 'fullwidth' %>
      </div>
      <div data-hook="admin_users_index_search_buttons">
        <%= button Spree.t(:search_users), 'search' %>
      </div>
 <% end %>
```

In my controller i have

```
Spree::Admin::UsersController.class_eval do
  def index
    @users = Spree::User.all.order(:email).
      ransack(params[:q]).
      result.
      page(params[:page]).
      per(params[:per_page])
   end
end
```

Now, a spree_user can have many roles and the role class is defined by spree as follows

```
module Spree
  class Role < Spree::Base
    has_many :role_users, class_name: "Spree::RoleUser", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :role_users
  end
end
```

There is a table `spree_roles_users` which connects users to roles. I want to add a dropdown select field to the search form listing all roles that have atleast one user belonging to it and use the specified role for the search as well. I know i would have to do a `collection_select` in the form for adding the role dropdown but am not sure exactly how to use it in this scenario.I added the following to the form

```
<%= f.collection_select :spree_roles_ids, Spree::Role.all, :id, :name %>
```

But it gives the error `undefined method 'spree_roles_ids' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00561a6a02a370>`

How can i fix this ?

Thank You

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `<%= f.collection_select :spree_roles_id, Spree::Role.all, :id, :name %>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to whitelist `spree_roles` association for `User` model
You can do it by adding following code in `spree.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Spree.user_class.whitelisted_ransackable_associations.push('spree_roles')
end
```

Now in `ransack` form

`<%= f.collection_select :spree_roles_id_eq, Spree::Role.all, :id, :name %>`

Please observe I have used `spree_roles_id_eq` instead of `spree_roles_id` as you have to tell ransack what should be your matching condition.
In this case, I am querying against equality clause.

Hope this helps.